# bjam glob 'exclude pattern' question

Tags: bjam, boost-build

According to the docs, bjam's glob operator accepts a 2nd argument which specifies a pattern to exclude, like so:

```
[ glob pattern : exclude ]
```

However bjam gives me an error complaining about the 2nd argument. It may be that my bjam version is too old.  Would anyone know at what version this 'exclude' feature was added? I'm using 3.1.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using 3.1.16 of Boost.Jam and Milestone 12 of Boost.Build, and the exclude parameter works fine for us.  What's your exact pattern and exclude arguments?

Comment: You're correct. I've been informed that this feature was added later than my version.

Comment: More specifically, it was added in "milestone 12". I'm using milestone 11 of boost build (although I'm using a more recent version than you of bjam, 3.1.17)  How this versioning scheme works, like most things related to bjam, is beyond me (at least beyond the effort I'm willing to expend on trivia)

Comment: boost jam is the core language, boost build is the collection of rules built in the underlying Jam langauge for common tasks.  Think of boost jam as the core language and boost build as the standard library.  They are split into two packages in some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu).  You should be able to upgrade to milestone 12 or later.